# Spring Batch to Write file to multiple destinations

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am currently writing spring batch where i am reading a XML data , processing it and then pass the processor result as `map<string,object>` to writer and implemented CompositeItemWriter. Following is the required output XML.

```
 <Company att1="value">
      <employees>
        <employee></employee>
         <employee></employee>
         <employee></employee>
      <employees>
    </Company>
```

Generated JAXB xjc classes for marshalling and unmarshalling.
  JAXB generated class looks like the below.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Company")
public class Company{
@XmlElements(name="employees" required="true")
}
```

> **JAXB Employee class**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="employees")
public class Employees
{
@XmlElement(name="Employee")
protected List<Employees> employee;
}
```

> Spring XML configuration file

```
<batch:job id="reportJob">
<batch:step id="step1">
<batch:tasklet>
<batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" 
 writer="compositeItemWriter" processor="filterReportProcessor"
 commit-interval="2">
 </batch:chunk>
 </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
</batch:job>



<!-- Filtering process -->
<bean id="filterReportProcessor" class="com.examples.FilterReportProcessor" />

<bean id="xmlItemReader" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
<property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="record" />
<property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/company.xml" />
<property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
</bean>

<!-- Read and map values to object, via jaxb2 -->
<bean id="reportUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="classesToBeBound">
<list>
    <value>com.examples.Company</value>
    <value>com.examples.Employees</value>
    <value>com.examples.Employee</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="compositeItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter">
<property name="delegates"/>
    <list>
       <ref bean="testXMlWriter">
  </list>
</bean>
<bean id="testXMlWriter" class="com.test.example.TestXMLWriter">
```

> **Processor and Writer :**

```
    public class FilterReportProcessor
    implement ItemProcessor<Employee,Map<String,Object>>{
    public Map<String,Object> process(Employee emplpyee) throws Exception{
    Map<String,Object> evnt = Mapper.crateMapping(emplpyee);
    return event; 
    }

    public class TestXMLWriter implemtes ItemWriter(Map<String,Object>){
    write(List <? extends Map<String, object>> lst){

    Employee e1 = new Employee();
    e1.setxxx(mapelementdata.item());

    Employees employs = new Employees();
    employs.add(e1);
    Comapany c1 = new Company();
    c1.add(employs);

   Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
   m.marshal(c1, resource.getFile());
  }
```

> Question :

XML file is overriding for each fixed commit-intervals, It is obvious that XML file creates after each commit-level. But i have to append all the `<employee>` objects to same XML file. how to implement this logic to append the `<employee>` objects after every commit interval ?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: how to append new xml records in same batch step excecution.

Comment: Modified question and reposted

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write to the same file , in that case i would recommend using FlatFileItemWriter instead of the custom writer you have and set the property appendAllowed to true , this would append to the file if it already exists.Move the processing logic to your processor and using lineAggregator to batch a number of lines together for a write.

If you do not want to do that then you have to resort to a little more complex coding , of opening the file in the beforeWrite method of a WriterListener, reading the content and then storing it in the context and then pushing it to the write method.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have to generate the XML output not the CSV. Also I have read the concept of StaxEventItemWriter from Spring but with that i have a complexity of writing the Root tag element with the Attributes.  Please look at the XML output mentioned at the starting of the question. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please add your input xml's

Comment: It looks same as my output xml expect the contents in employee gets changed

Comment: Company is the root tag with attributes startdate, end date,id.. Employees and Employee ..